# How to find Location Area Code in iOS

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I need to obtain the LAC of a Cell Tower in iOS. I know that we can obtain MCC and MNC in FieldTest Mode. CTCarrier provides MCC and MNC as well. VAFieldTest (http://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest) gives us CellId as well.

How can I obtain LAC in iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not provide any public API to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you published your application, it won't be accepted by Apple.